# SELECT and GROUP BY month efficiently

Tags: mysql, sql, select, optimization, group-by

I have a column of type `date`. I want to group rows per month for a particular year.
I did the following:

```
SELECT SUM(price), DATE_FORMAT(production_date, '%Y%m')  
FROM TABLE  
WHERE YEAR(production_date) = ?    
GROUP BY 2
```

Is there a better/more efficient way to do this?

Comment: You may be interested in checking out codereview.stackexchange.com, that site seems to specialize in this sort of question.

Comment: what is meaning of `GROUP BY 2` ?

Comment: ^ GROUP BY second column (yes, mysql supports such semantics). To OP: it's impossible to answer properly without knowing full context (structure, size, indexes etc.)

Comment: @AlmaDo:Fair point.But using functions disables indexes and how the query is formed now would not use them.So basically I am interested in different forms of expressing the saame thing

Comment: If your query will be run often enough, I would recommend to create separate month and year columns (or, may be, even "year-month") and store those parts of your date in it. If you'll create index by that column, it will certainly increase performance - however, increase amount will depend of cardinality for that index

Answer (score 1):

Instead of specifying the year using the `YEAR` function

```
SELECT SUM(price), DATE_FORMAT(production_date, '%Y%m')  
FROM TABLE  
WHERE YEAR(production_date) = 2014
GROUP BY 2
```

specify it like this

```
SELECT SUM(price), DATE_FORMAT(production_date, '%Y%m')  
FROM TABLE  
WHERE production_date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
GROUP BY 2
```

The 2nd query enables the db to use an index on `production_date`

Comment: If there is an index by `production_date` column, then second query will use that index for WHERE clause, yes - but I believe OP request is about - how to optimize GROUP BY indexing (and second query won't be able to produce index usage for grouping)

Comment: @AlmaDo true, if op is only interested in optimizing `GROUP BY` then this won't help but the title refers to both `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` so maybe they're looking for any optimization? op will have to clarify

Answer (score 0):

you are almost there :)

```
SELECT SUM(price), MONTH(production_date)  
FROM TABLE  
WHERE YEAR(production_date) = ?    
GROUP BY 2
```

Comment: Either `MONTH` or `DATE_FORMAT` : __both__ will fail to use index in common case. That's because using function for MySQL almost always causes impossibility of using index. Thus, there's no difference with OP query in terms of performance